# Are there any differences between (in the terms of compatibility) using Windows+miktex and macOS+mactex?

Tags: miktex, compiling, mactex, compilation-error

I'm having an issue compiling document on macOS using *Texpad + mactex*. The document was originally written on *Windows* while author used *miktex* distribution.

Is this a common issue that these are not compatible? The error is probably with the templates that are a part of the document, but I'm not hundred percent sure.

Thank You.

This is my error (I posted here before, but I was asked to provide definition / example of the class that is causing the issue), here is the error with \X@artonum class.

---

I'm getting this error while building a project I received from colleague. The document structure is defined in templates. Is it possible to read something from this errors:

```
    \@begindocumenthook ...ter \X@rtonum \r@FirstPage 
                                                  } \setcounter {numpages}{-...
l.3 \begin{document}

./m_2019.tex:3: Argument of \X@rtonum has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.3 \begin{document}

Runaway argument?
./m_2019.tex:3: Paragraph ended before \X@rtonum was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.3 \begin{document}

./m_2019.tex:3: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.3 \begin{document}

Runaway argument?
./m_2019.tex:3: Paragraph ended before \calc@post@scan was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.3 \begin{document}
```

This is the definition of `\X@rtonum` and `\r@FirstPage` in case it might help resolving this problem (I still can't compile the `.tex` document):

```
% counter that will store the total number of pages
\newcounter{numpages}
% this all has to be done after .aux is read
\AtBeginDocument{
  % make sure these two cross-referencing commands are defined, at least to \relax
  \@ifundefined{r@FirstPage}{\relax}{\relax}
  \@ifundefined{r@LastPage}{\relax}{\relax}
  % \X@rtonum gets the page number from an \r@... command
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\def\X@rtonum#1#2#3#4#5{#2}}{\def\X@rtonum#1#2{#2}}
  % start with zero
  \setcounter{numpages}{0}
  % define \X@FirstPage to store the first page number
  \ifx\r@FirstPage\relax
    % we store 0 if nothing better is availible
    \gdef\X@FirstPage{0}
  \else
    % we store the real value of \pageref{FirstPage}, just the problem is that \pageref itself is unexpandable
    \xdef\X@FirstPage{\expandafter\X@rtonum\r@FirstPage}
    % the larger FirstPage, the smaller number of pages
    \setcounter{numpages}{-\X@FirstPage}
    % correction by 1
    \stepcounter{numpages}
  \fi
  % the same again for LastPage
  \ifx\r@LastPage\relax
    \gdef\X@LastPage{0}
  \else
    \xdef\X@LastPage{\expandafter\X@rtonum\r@LastPage}
    % the larger LastPage, the larger number of pages
    \addtocounter{numpages}{\X@LastPage}
  \fi
  % \AP@page stores the correct first page number
  \ifdefined\AP@page
    \setcounter{page}{\AP@page}
  \fi
}
% \AP@{<article>}{<key>}{<value>} is stored in the file <issue>.ap and is loaded at the end of the class-file
\def\AP@#1#2#3{
  \begingroup
    % store the <article> key
    \edef\reserved@a{#1}%
    % define \AP@<key> = <value> but only if <article> is correct
    \ifx\reserved@a\X@articlename\relax
      \expandafter\xdef\csname AP@#2\endcsname{#3}%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
```

This is m_paper.tex

```
\documentclass[eprint]{publisher}

\begin{document}

\title[Evaluation of Hopkinson Bar Experiments using multiple DIC tools]{Evaluation of Hopkinson Bar Experiments using multiple Digital
Image Correlation Software Tools}
\correspondingauthor[Joe Doe]{Joe Doe}{my}{john@doe.com}
\author[J. Doe]{John Doe}{their}
\author[J. Doe_2]{Joh Doe_2}{my}
\author[J. D\'{a}mal]{John D\'{a}mal }{my}
\author[J. D\'{a}mal]{J. D\'{a}mal}{my}
\institution{my}{University Czech}
\institution{their}{University Germany} 

\begin{abstract}
This is abstract
\end{abstract}

\keywords{keyword_1, keyword_2, keyword_3, keyword_4}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

First section


\begin{acknowledgements}
\mbox{The research was supported by ...}
\end{acknowledgements}


\bibliographystyle{publisher}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to post the full `m_paper` class or a link to it otherwise no one can run this code and debug it.

Comment: I have extended the topic by m_paper (I cut the text (I have to respect authors) while the main structure remains - the error is the same)...

Comment: you have provided no link to `publisher.cls` so we can not run your test file or trace the error that you get.

Comment: Sorry, https://github.com/JKhay/LaTeX/blob/master/publisher.cls . Please, check, whether the link works (it should, I have checked twice). Than You very much for you help.

Comment: thansk a link to the publishers copy would have been better (your question is archived here forever and github link will probably break) but it's OK for now.

Comment: The class as posted does not work at all. It starts off `LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class \`publisher',
               but the document class provides \`actapoly'.
` which isn't a fatal error but a very bad sign that things are broken, then it reports `! Undefined control sequence.
l.96 \ifactapoly@approc`  which means that the file is not usable.

Comment: Note that this error is not a windows/mac difference, the file as posted can not work in any tex distribution.

Comment: That is true - I have changed the name for the publisher - I get the posted error with `actapoly.cls` which is the original name - I didn't want to name it after its origin (I get this from Acta publisher to correct the article and didn't want to share it in the first place, but I can't get over the compiling error, so I haven't come with anything else) however, the names are in the `.cls` anyway. So, it should be called `actapoly.cls` and the document class: `\documentclass[eprint]{actapoly}`, then I get the error that I've posted. Sorry for this complications.

Comment: If you download and open the .zip - you get the full templates: https://github.com/JKhay/LaTeX .

Comment: No sorry it is up to you to make a small self contained file that runs and produces the error that you want to ask about, I am not downloading zip files.

Comment: you will not get the error that you posted from the posted document even if you change the class name, you will get the undefined command error that I give above.

Comment: Hello, I'm the original author of `actapoly.cls`, though I'm not actually maintaining it anymore. I know there are some issues with a (I believe 2018) update to `hyperref` which causes one of the very bad hacks I used there to fail. However, we never suggested that anyone should load the class using `\documentclass{publisher}`; it looks like someone took the `cls` file and renamed it to another name (and possibly did some other modifications).

Comment: No, that was a misunderstanding. I used `\documentclass{actapoly}`. It's now uploaded here: https://github.com/JKhay/LaTeX/blob/master/LaTeX_2.zip . Every class name should be as original and I'm still getting compilation error - both on macOS and Windows... I haven't changed the `hyperref` or imported any `hyperref` package...

Comment: yo' (Hi). I forgot to say that I hope you don't mind sharing the .cls here. However, I'm quite desperate with compiling issues and the editor who provided me with articles, templates, etc. is not a "LaTeX expert" and to my surprise, his computer compiled the file - I have no idea why. Would you mind giving me any contact or something (I'm not sure whether it's possible to sent PM), so I'm able to directly chat with you if you have some time to spare from time to time. I've just started to "work" for Acta and from time to time I may have some questions (hopefully, not many)...

Comment: @JoshE. No worries. Well, it is available to the public, just not 100% easily :) As Ulrike pointed out below, there was a change in treatment of something, I just never really got to find out what's actually going on.

Comment: @yo' I'm glad I haven't cross any rule posting the template, but it was being too long since I was stuck with one particular error... that happens. It was really depressing for me seeing that other computer can compile the article (without Ulrike's suggestion) while mine cannot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class won't work in a current texsystem, may it be miktex or texlive, it contains code (`\@ifundefined{r@FirstPage}{\relax}{\relax}`) that relies on a side effect which isn't there anymore.

As a work around you can try to add  the following to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\r@FirstPage\relax
\let\r@LastPage\relax
\makeatother
```

Comment: YES!!! Thank you very much! It finally works! I don't know how you guy manage to know the ropes in the log files, but I was struggling with this over 2 weeks.

Comment: Can I ask you one more favor... :) Are you able to tell me where is the header and footer defined - its content and mostly format - whether the .tex produce capital/small letters, name shortcuts/full names in header?

Answer (score 5):

There are essentially no differences between miktex and texlive/mactex  at the document level unless the document uses `shell-escape` (`\write18`)  and runs a windows command.

Far more likely is that the two systems have different versions of latex and packages installed, this can happen even if both systems are running miktex, or both texlive.

Add `\listfiles` and compare your log files.

Comment: I have uploaded the particular issue (I have posted here before but still can't solve it). I have extended the error with the \X@rtonum definition. I hope it helps. I have also just tried Windows + miktex and I've dealt with a similar error. I really don't know what's the issue. I'd highly appreciate if you can look at that. Thank You.

Comment: @JoshE. please don't post disconnected fragments, construct a small test file that people can run and debug.